# How eigenvector evolves when columns of matrix multiplies?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, eigenfunctions

$IX=AX$

So for the above equation, X is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalues of 1.
Let's multiply each column of A with a positive number bigger than one and call the new matrix B where A and B both are square matrices and I is the identity matrix.

$IX^{'}=BX^{'}$

My question is that what can we say about the $X^{'}$
Can we say all elements of $X^{'}$ are bigger than $X$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-ÁlvarezThanks for your comment. I have not thought this way.

Comment: If you multiply every column by the same positive number $a$, then every $1$-eigenvector of $A$ is an $a$-eigenvector of $B$. If you multiply different columns by different numbers, I don't think you can say much of anything. In particular, it should be pretty easy to write down examples where all the scale factors are bigger than one, but at least one entry of an eigenvector gets bigger and one entry gets smaller. Why are you interested in this problem?